# Свой редактор кода

Tags: javascript

Есть редактор кода. Хочу, чтобы когда я написал любой элемент, например `<div>`, то тогда он закрашивался в красный цвет

```js
function runCode() {
 var content = document.getElementById('sourceCode').value;
 var iframe = document.getElementById('targetCode');
 iframe = (iframe.contentWindow)?iframe.contentWindow:(iframe.contentDocument)?
 iframe.contentDocument.document: iframe.contentDocument;

 iframe.document.open();
 iframe.document.write(content);
 iframe.document.close();
 return false;
}
runCode();
```

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
textarea, iframe {
  border: 2px solid #ddd;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
   <tr>
     <td width="50%" scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
     <td width="50%" scope="col" align="left">
      <input onclick="runCode()" type="button" value="Run Code">
     </td>
 </tr>
     <td>
      <form>
       <strong>Code</strong>
       <textarea name="sourceCode" id="sourceCode">
        <html>
        <head>
         <title>Hello</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <h1>Hello</h1>
         <p>Write code</p>
        </body>
        </html>
       </textarea>
      </form>
     </td>
     <td><strong>OutPut</strong><iframe name="targetCode" id="targetCode"></iframe></td>
 </table>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ("textarea").on ("change",()=>{
      $ ("textarea").сss ({
           borderColor : "red"
       })
})
```

Как то так.